# Perfino System Requirements

Tags: perfino

We're planning to evaluate and eventually potentially purchase perfino. I went quickly through the docs and cannot find the system requirements for the installation. Also I cannot find it's compatibility with JBoss 7.1. Can you provide details please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hard system requirements for disk space, it depends on the amount of business transactions that you're recording. All data will be consolidated, so the database reaches a maximum size after a while, but it's not possible to say what that size will be. Consolidation times can be configured in the general settings.

There are also no hard system requirements for CPU and physical memory. A low-end machine will have no problems monitoring 100 JVMs, but the exact details again depend on the amount of monitored business transactions.

JBoss 7.1 is supported. "Supported" means that web service and EJB calls can be tracked between JVMs, otherwise all application servers work with perfino.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any official system requirements, but this is what we figured out experimentally.

We collect about 10,000 transactions a minute from 8 JVMs. We have a lot of distinct and long SQL queries. We use AWS machine with 2 VCPUs and 8GB RAM.

When the Perfino GUI is not being used, the CPU load is low. However, for the GUI to work properly, we had to modify perfino_service.vmoptions:
`-Xmx6000m`. Before that we had experienced multiple `OutOfMemoryError` in Perfino when filtering in the transactions view. After changing the memory settings, the GUI is running fine.

This means that you need a machine with about 8GB RAM. I guess this depends on the number of distinct transactions you collect. Our limit is high, at 30,000.

After 6 weeks of usage, there's 7GB of files in the perfino directory. Perfino can clear old recordings after a configurable time.